# sqlalchemy: override automatic FROM clause creation from select

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

If I have in sqlalchemy:

```
select([foo.c.id]).select.where(foo.c.id == bar.c.val).select_from(foo)
```

I get SQL that looks like:

```
SELECT foo.id
FROM foo, bar
WHERE foo.id = bar.val
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT foo.id
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id = bar.val
```

I realize that this does not make sense in and of itself, but I am compiling the expression and nesting it in an exists clause of a delete statement on the table `bar`, so `bar.val` makes sense in the context - the full statement will look something like:

```
DELETE FROM bar WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT foo.id
  FROM foo
  WHERE foo.id = bar.val
)
```

How can I turn off the automatic `FROM` clause creation in SQL alchemy?

Answer (score 0):

For your case you do not need to turn it off. Just create a complete `delete` statement, and `sqlalchemy` will figure it out:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import exists
q2 = bar.delete().where(exists(q1))
print(q2)
```

produces:

```
DELETE FROM bar WHERE EXISTS (SELECT foo.id
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id = bar.id)
```